# C++: Undefined reference to function error

Tags: c++, function, reference

So I have a program whose purpose is to calculate the total bill for medical expenses using overloaded functions. There is a problem though when I try to call the function which is inside the if/else statement block.

Before I compile it there's really no indicator that lets me know there's an issue and I'm stuck, I'd appreciate some help. This is the complete error message I get: In function `main': main.cpp:(.text+0x14d): undefined reference to` bill(float, float)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x25b): undefined reference to `bill(float, float, float)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
compiler exit status 1

here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

float choice, service_charge, test_charge, medicine_charge;

float bill(float, float);
float bill(float, float, float);

int main()
{
  
  cout << "Please input 1 if you are a member of"
    << " the dental plan" << ", Input any other number if you are not: " << endl;
  cin >> choice;

  if (choice == 1)
  {
    cout << "Please input the service charge: " << endl;
    cin >> service_charge;

    cout << "Please input the test charge: " << endl;
    cin >> test_charge;

    bill(service_charge, test_charge);
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "Please input the service charge: " << endl;
    cin >> service_charge;

    cout << "Please input the test charges: " << endl;
    cin >> test_charge; 

    cout << "Please input the medicine charges: " << endl;
    cin >> medicine_charge;

    bill(service_charge, test_charge, medicine_charge);
  }
  
  return 0;
}

float bill(float &refservice, float &reftest)
{
  cout << "The total bill is: $" << endl;
  return refservice + reftest;
}

float bill(float &refservice, float &reftest, float &refmed)
{
  cout << "The total bill is: $" << endl;
  return refservice + reftest + refmed;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of the prototype, `float bill(float, float);`, is not equivalent to the actual function definition's signature, which is `float bill(float &refservice, float &reftest)`. Your other prototype and function have the same issue. Thus, the compiler doesn't recognize that you've already defined that function. You have to change the signature of your prototype to match. Your prototypes in that case would look like:

```
float bill(float&, float&);
float bill(float&, float&, float&);
```

One thing to note is that it's not clear why you have to pass those floats by reference, since you're not modifying them in any way.